# What use does the unary & operator have in this piece of C++ code?

Tags: c++, directx

In an example for a little game framework (that does work), there are the lines:

```
ID3D10Device* device;
ID3D10Buffer* pBuffer;
```

followed by the line

```
 device()->CreateBuffer(&bd, NULL, &pBuffer());
```

The third argument requires a pointer, so why do you need to put an ampersand before pBuffer? an ampersand gets a memory address right? But pBuffer is already a pointer so what does the ampersand do to it?

Comment: This probably belongs on StackOverflow, as it's not really game development related. Also, did you intend to write "device()" and "pBuffer()" in your third line? That seems like a typo; at the very least it changes the meaning of the code somewhat.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As described in the [ID3D10Device::CreateBuffer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb173544%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) page, this function simply requires a pointer to a pointer which is used to contain the output of the function.

```
HRESULT CreateBuffer(
  [in]   const D3D10_BUFFER_DESC *pDesc,
  [in]   const D3D10_SUBRESOURCE_DATA *pInitialData,
  [out]  ID3D10Buffer **ppBuffer
);
```

As always in C/C++, adding an & simply returns the address of the variable. In this case, the address of the pointer.

Answer (score 1):

The & is also used as a [reference operator](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/). It returns the address of the variable it's referencing too. If you had a function that took the pointer directly as a parameter, then the function will be working directly with the pointer (useful for pointer arithmetic).

Pointer pointers to resources are quite common in the D3D APIs. You usually don't want to access them directly as it's not of any benefit.